# function current_user

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I create a function that shows only the OID of the connected user?
In this case you only have to display the number 10 when calling the function

[image]

```
postgres=# select current_user;
 current_user 
--------------
 postgres
(1 fila)
```

In this case you only have to display the number 10 when calling the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look it up in `pg_roles`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION current_userid() RETURNS oid
   STABLE PARALLEL SAFE LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT oid FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = current_user';
```

Comment: Works! Thanks Laurenz